# Best approach for a modular node.js/socket.io/express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io-1.0

I'm currectly creating an app using Node.JS that makes use of Express and Socket.io. As time progresses it's becoming increasingly difficult to deal with one file, I'm in the process of moving certain things out that I know how but was wondering on the best approach to do this.

I have a private area constructor similar to:

`privateArea.js`

```
function privateArea(props) {
    this.id = props.id;
    this.name = props.name;
    this.users = [];
}

privateArea.prototype.addUser = function(socketId) {
    this.users.push(socketId);
};

module.exports = privateArea;
```

I'd like to have this also have access to the `socket.io` variable that's been setup for use in a separate `sockets.js` file that can be included via the main `app.js` and a seperate file for `express.js`

So I'd like the structure as follows:

```
project
| app.js - joins it all together
| express.js - initialises and manages all express routing
| privateArea.js - constructor for private areas - must be able to reference socket.io
| sockets.js - initialises and manages all socket.io sockets and events
```

Any help/examples would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See [express generator](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#executable) for the standard way of creating express apps.

Comment: @digitalfresh Thanks for your comment, any ideas on how to pass the socket.io object to my `privateArea` constructor?

Answer (score 2):

I use socket.io and express quite often in my projects, and I've developed a template which makes things easy. I like to have a fail-over in case the socket connections drops for some reason, or if a socket connection cannot be established. So I create http channels as well as socket channels. Here's a basic module template:

```
module.exports = function () {
    var exported = {};

    var someFunction = function (done) {
        //.. code here..//
        if (typeof done === "function") {
            done(null, true);
        }
    };
    // export the function
    exported.someFunction = someFunction;

    var apicalls = function (app) {
        app.get("/module/someFunction", function (req, res) {
             res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
             someFunction(function (err, response) {
                 if (err) return res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
                 res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
             });
        });
    };
    exported.apicalls = apicalls;

    var socketcalls = function (io) {
        io.on("connection", function (socket) {
            socket.on('module-someFunction', function () {
                someFunction(function (err, response) {
                    if (err) return socket.emit('module-someFunction', err);
                    socket.emit('module-someFunction', response);
                });
            });
        });
    };
    exported.socketcalls = socketcalls;

    return exported;
}
```

So to use this, I'd first need to include the module in my app.js file like this:

```
var mymod = require('./myModule.js');
```

And then I can enable access to this service from HTTP and over the websocket like this:

```
mymod.apicalls(app);   // passing express to the module
mymod.socketcalls(io); // passing socket.io to the module
```

Finally, from the front-end, I can check to see if I have a socket connection, and if so, I use the socket to emit "module-someFunction". If I don't have a socket connection, the front-end will do an AJAX call instead to "/module/someFunction" which will hit the same function on the server side that it would've had I used the socket connection.

As an added bonus, if I need to utilize the function within the server, I could do that as well since the function is exported. That would look like this:

```
mymod.someFunction(function (err, response) {
    // ... handle result here ... //
});
```

Comment: awesome and thank you. Ive been looking for how to possibly modularize socket.io outside of the app/express initializing server files and this is perfect